# Mongoose / mongoDB - How to sort by string?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

May somebody help me how to short string at mongo.

```
     [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$bulan",
            "total_vote": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$multiply": "$nilai"
                }
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": 1
        }
    }],
```

and here's the result :

```
[
  { _id: '1', total_vote: 142, count: 23 },
  { _id: '11', total_vote: 50, count: 1 },
  { _id: '2', total_vote: 320, count: 160 },
  { _id: '3', total_vote: 94, count: 47 },
  { _id: '4', total_vote: 120, count: 60 },
  { _id: '5', total_vote: 650, count: 13 },
  { _id: '7', total_vote: 350, count: 7 },
  { _id: '8', total_vote: 102, count: 2 }
]
```

I have stuck why _id : 11 is after _id : 1.

Please if there's anyone can help me with this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: See [Comparison Sort Order -strings - collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB can't sort by numbers stored as String. Here is the workaround

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      newId: {
        $toInt: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      newId: 1
    }
  },
  {
      $project:{
          newId:0
      }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oJvbDlMMb59)

Comment: How about "_id": {$toInt : "$bulan"}, is it working ?

Comment: That should work. I answered based on the output and considered that if you need to keep it as String.